# Как отключить нажатие колесика?

Tags: html, css, javascript

http://www.toyotapriusprojects.com/ на этом сайте если нажать колесико и начать двигать вправо то он выходит за пределы страницы.Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии колесика ничего не происходило?Или движение было только вверх и вниз?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')!=-1) ie=1;
else ie=0;
document.onmousedown=function(e) {
        e=e||window.event;
        if ((ie && e.button==4) || (!ie && e.button==1)) return false
    }
```

Comment: это функция делает только вниз и вверх да?

Comment: нет, она отключает колёсико. Должна отключать. Но крутить можно, нажимать нельзя

Comment: ааа...спасибо=)